# O que é o teorema mestre (master theorem)?

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

O que é o teorema mestre (master theorem)? Qual sua importância na análise de complexidade de algoritmos?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Divisão e conquista

A estrutura de muitos algoritmos eficientes segue o paradigma da divisão e conquista.  Esse paradigma (ou estratégia de projeto de algoritmos) consiste no seguinte:

- A instância dada do problema é dividida em duas ou mais instâncias menores,
- Cada instância menor é resolvida usando o próprio algoritmo que está sendo definido
- As soluções das instâncias menores são combinadas para produzir uma solução da instância original.

### Recorrência

É uma técnica matemática que permite definir sequências, conjuntos, operações ou até mesmo algoritmos partindo de problemas particulares para problemas genéricos. Ou seja, por intermédio de uma regra pode-se calcular qualquer termo em função do(s) antecessor(es) imediato(s).

### Teorema Mestre

Muitas das recorrências que ocorrem na análise de algoritmos de **divisão e conquista** têm a forma:

```
 F(n)  =  a F(n/2) + cn^k
```

O seguinte **Teorema Mestre** dá a solução *(em termos assintóticos)* de todas essas recorrências.

> Teorema:  Sejam a um número natural não nulo, k um número natural, e c um número real positivo.  Seja F uma função que leva números naturais em números reais positivos e satisfaz a recorrência (*) para n = 21, 22, 23, …  Suponha que F é assintoticamente não decrescente, ou seja, que existe n1 tal que F(n) ≤ F(n+1) para todo n ≥ n1.  Nessas condições,
>
> - se  lg a > k  então  F está em Θ(n^lg a) ,
> - se  lg a = k  então  F está em Θ(n^k lg n) ,
> - se  lg a < k  então  F está em Θ(n^k) .

### Generalização

O **Teorema Mestre** pode ser generalizado como segue para tratar de recorrências como

```
 F(n)  =  a F(n/b) + cn^k.
```

### Sua Importância(uso)*

O Teorema Mestre permite a você uma maneira de contornar este problema, comparando um algoritmo recursivo com outros algoritmos, o que lhe permite estimar os **limites superior e inferior** para a solução.

Em outras palavras, **Teorema Mestre** calcula os recursos necessários para executar um algoritmo recursivo, como o tempo de execução em um computador. O método mestre usa o que é conhecido como notação **Big O** para descrever o comportamento assintótico de funções, ou seja, a rapidez com que crescem em direção ao seu limite.

Fontes de pesquisa:

- [Divisão e Conquista](http://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/analise_de_algoritmos/aulas/divide-and-conquer.html)
- [Relação de Recorrência](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rela%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_recorr%C3%AAncia)
- [IME USP](http://www.ime.usp.br/%7Epf/analise_de_algoritmos/aulas/recorrencias.html)
- [Método Mestre de Recorrência](http://pt.wingwit.com/P/computer-programming-languages/87229.html)

Comment: "Um algoritmo de forma recursiva não tem solução, o que fica evidente na manipulação algébrica." - Pedro, essa frase está estranha, algoritmos recursivos têm solução, basta ver as soluções de recorrência do próprio link que você passou!

Comment: @CarlosCinelli eu tirei essa parte.. obrigado