# Como fazer uma busca ternária (divide a procura em um 1/3) em C?

Tags: c, algoritmo, estrutura-de-dados

Tentei utilizar várias variações desse código com a menor complexidade que consegui pensar, mas nenhum deu certo para todos os números procurados. O vetor inserido já é ordenado. Já tentei também resolver analisando os números truncados para float quando o decimal da divisão de "terco" é maior ou igual a 0.5, mas não resolveu.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int buscaTernaria(int n, int *v, int num);

int main(){
    int n;
    printf("Entre tamanho do vetor: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int* v = malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    printf("Entre os elementos do vetor: ");

    int i = 0;
    while(i < n){
        scanf("%d", &v[i]);
        i++;
    }

    int num;
    printf("Entre número que deseja encontrar: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    int search = buscaTernaria(n, v, num);

    if(search != -1) printf("O número %d é elemento do vetor", num);
    else printf("Número não encontrado como elemento do vetor");
}

int buscaTernaria(int n, int *v, int num){
    int i = 0;
    int f = n-1;
    
    while(i < f){
        int terco; 
        if((float)(i+f)/3 - (i+f)/3 < 0.5) terco = (i+f)/3; 
        else terco = (i+f)/3 + 1;
        
        if(v[terco] < num) i = terco;
        else if(v[f - terco] < num) i = f - terco;
        
        if(v[f - terco] > num) f = f - terco;   
        else if(v[terco] > num) f = terco;
        
        printf("i:%d f:%d\n", i, f);
        
        int m = (i+f)/2;
        if(v[m] == num || v[m] == num+1) return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Leu o código que eu mostrei? Não precisa ficar com a busca ternária: todos os segmentos são similares e o número deles não faz diferença. Não precisa usar `float`. Uma única linha e pode estender o último segmento para compensar o arredontamento da disão por inteiro.

Comment: Essa linha `if ((final - fim) < seg) fim = final;` onde `final` é o último índice válido e 'fim' é o últomo índice do segmento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem alguns problemas com o seu algoritmo:

- seu algoritmo não imprime a posição do elemento pesquisado no vetor de entrada
  `if(search != -1) printf("O número %d é elemento do vetor", num);`
- seu algoritmo apenas imprime `-1` se o elemento pesquisado não for encontrado e `1` caso encontre o elemento pesquisado
  `if(v[m] == num || v[m] == num+1) return 1;`
- seu algoritmo não faz uma pesquisa ternária, ele apenas pesquisa o primeiro terço do vetor em busca do elemento pesquisado e caso o elemento esteja nos outros dois terços do vetor entra em loop.

Como o Stack Overflow não é uma mídia presencial é mais fácil descartar e implementar um novo algoritmo do que corrigir.

Primeira coisa a se deixar claro é o conceito de pesquisa ternária.

Uma pesquisa ternária é um técnica de pesquisa que usa uma estratégia de [divisão e conquista](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34868/o-que-%C3%A9-o-teorema-mestre-master-theorem) para determinar a posição de um valor específico em um vetor classificado, no caso em ordem crescente.
Enquanto que na busca binária o vetor é dividido em dois campos de pesquisa, na pesquisa ternária o vetor é dividido em três campos de pesquisa os terços direito, central e esquerdo, seguindo o sentido de leitura ocidental.
Seu algoritmo pode ser implementado de forma [iterativa ou recursiva](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/21551/quando-usar-recurs%C3%A3o-e-quando-usar-la%C3%A7os), no exemplo será implementado de forma iterativa.

Um algoritmo iterativo de pesquisa ternária recebe como entradas um vetor classificado em ordem crescente mais um valor a ser buscado o índice, e:

- determina os índices do primeiro e do último elementos do vetor que será o campo de pesquisa.
- enquanto o índice do primeiro elemento do escopo de pesquisa for menor ou igual ao o índice do último elemento do campo de pesquisa...

  - a partir do comprimento do campo de pesquisa determina os índices dos terços direito e esquerdo.
  - verifica, caso o elemento cujo índice é o terço direito seja igual ao valor buscado abandone a função retornado o índice terço direito.
  - verifica, caso o elemento cujo índice é o terço esquerdo seja igual ao valor buscado abandone a função retornado o índice terço esquerdo.
  - verifica, caso o valor do buscado seja menor ao elemento cujo índice é o terço direito:

    - determina que o índice do final campo de pesquisa será o índice do terço direito menos 1.
    - continua com a próxima iteração.
  - verifica, caso o valor do buscado seja maior ao elemento cujo índice é o terço esquerdo:

    - determina o índice do inicial do campo de pesquisa será o índice do terço esquerdo mais 1.
    - continua com a próxima iteração.
  - determina que o campo de pesquisa será o índice do terço central.
- como o elemento não foi encontrado retorna -1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int buscaTernaria(int size, int *arr, int num);

int main(){
    int n = 10;                                     //Tamanho do vetor
    int v[] = {6,8,27,53,104,225,369,507,801,999};  //Vetor
    int num = 801;                                  //Numero a ser pesquisado

    int pos = buscaTernaria(n, v, num);
    if(pos != -1) printf("O número %d é elemento %d do vetor", num, pos);
    else printf("Número não encontrado como elemento do vetor");
}

int buscaTernaria(int size, int *arr, int num){
    int inicio = 0;
    int fim = size-1;

    while(inicio<=fim){
      int terco_direito = inicio + (fim - inicio )/3;
      int terco_esquerdo = fim - (fim - inicio )/3;
      if (num == arr[terco_direito]) return terco_direito;
      if (num == arr[terco_esquerdo]) return terco_esquerdo;
      if (num < arr[terco_direito]){
        fim = terco_direito - 1;
        continue;
      }
      if (num > arr[terco_esquerdo]){
        inicio = terco_esquerdo + 1;
        continue;
      }
      inicio = terco_direito + 1;
      fim = terco_esquerdo - 1;
    }
    return -1;
}
//O número 801 é elemento de índice 8 do vetor
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/8pb9Ks)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

- Nunca entendo o propósito de escrever um programa interativo cuja interatividade possa ser evitada. E é o caso aqui. Porque ler o vetor a cada teste? Ele tem que estar ordenado e nada tem a ver com o problema em si da tal busca ternária. Isso quer dizer que além de ter que digitar o vetor a cada teste tem que ficar atento para manter a ordem.
- Porque alocar o vetor dinamicamente ao invés de testar com um tamanho qualquer?
- porque nunca testar o retorno de `scanf()` se não faz sentido seguir se não leu nada?
- porque não liberar a memória ao final mesmo sendo um programa simples de teste?

```
    int buscaTernaria(int n, int *v, int num)
```

Porque retornar `-1` ou `1`? Não seria muito mais conveniente retornar a posição do vetor onde está o elemento ou um valor negativo se o elemento não fosse encontrado?

Acho que o código como postado seria bem simplificado se tivesse `um_terco` e `dois_tercos` computados para simplificar o loop.

De todo modo vou deixar um exemplo que funciona para busca ternária ou binária ou `n-aria` para `N` segmentos e que pode usar para comparar.

**Eis o protótipo:**

```
typedef long long int LLI;
typedef unsigned long long int ULL;

ULL busca_N_aria(LLI alvo, LLI* vetor, size_t inicio, size_t final);
```

Deixei esses `typedef` para poder usar matrizes muito grandes e não ter que digitar toda hora esses tipos compridos. E usei `size_t` porque são índices afinal e não podem ser negativos.

```
    const int n_seg = 3;  // 3 para busca ternaria
```

No exemplo essa linha define a busca ternária. Um `2` seria para a busca binária  normal e um 8 faria a busca em 8 segmentos por vez, por exemplo.
Claro que poderia ser um argumento.

#### o código para a função

```
// busca 'alvo' no vetor 'vec' entre os indices
// 'inicio' e 'final'. O vetor e suposto ordenado.
ULL busca_N_aria(LLI alvo, LLI* vec, size_t inicio, size_t final)
{
    const int n_seg = 3;  // 3 para busca ternaria
    if (vec[inicio] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[inicio] == alvo) return inicio;
    if (vec[final] < alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[final] == alvo) return final;
    // define o tamanho de cada segmento
    size_t seg = (final - inicio - 2) / n_seg; 
    if (seg <= 0) seg = 1;
    size_t ini = inicio + 1;
    size_t fim = ini + seg;
    while (1)
    {
        if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
        if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
        if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;  // era o ultimo
        // esta no meio desse segmento entao
        if (vec[fim] > alvo) return busca_N_aria(alvo, vec, ini+1, fim-1);
        ini += seg; // reajusta
        fim += seg;
        if ((final - fim) < seg) fim = final;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

#### outra maneira simples 2-aria 3-aria ou N-aria

```
ULL busca_N_aria(
    LLI alvo, LLI* vec, size_t inicio, size_t final)
{
    const int n_seg = 3;  // 3 para busca ternaria
    if (vec[inicio] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[inicio] == alvo) return inicio;
    if (vec[final] < alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[final] == alvo) return final;
    size_t ini = inicio + 1; // busca entre
    size_t fim = final - 1; // os limites
    while (1)
    {
        size_t seg = (fim - ini) / n_seg;
        if (seg <= 0) seg = 1;
        fim = ini + seg;
        if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
        if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
        if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;  // era o ultimo
        if (vec[fim] > alvo)
        {   // busca nesse segmento
            ini += 1;
            fim -= 1;
        }
        else
        {   // segue adiante
            ini += seg;  // reajusta
            fim += seg;
            if ((final - fim) < seg) fim = final;
        }
    }
    return -1; // nao vai passar aqui
}
```

Esta função faz a busca binária ou ternária ou centenária bastando mudar a constante `n_seg` como a anterior

#### Usando a mesma alteração para corrigir o código original

```
int buscaTernaria(int alvo, int* vec, int num)
{
    int ini = 0; // busca entre
    int final = num - 1; // os limites
    int fim = final;  
    if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
    if (vec[fim] < alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;
    while (1)
    {
        int terco = (fim-ini) / 3;
        if (terco <= 0) terco = 1;
        fim = ini + terco;
        if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
        if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
        if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;  // era o ultimo
        if (vec[fim] > alvo)
        {  // busca nesse segmento
            ini += 1;
            fim -= 1;
        }
        else
        {   // segue adiante: proximo terco
            ini += terco;  // reajusta
            fim += terco; // limites
            if ((final - fim) < terco) fim = final;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

- mudei os nomes de algumas variáveis
- no loop achei mais simples a função não sair do `while()` e simplesmente retornar ao concluir a busca
- o último `if` corrige o problema do tamanho dos segmentos ao invés de usar contas e `float`

#### um programa de teste

O programa abaixo não é interativo e faz o simples:

- aloca um vetor de tamanho `N` e preenche com valores **pares** ordenados.
- num loop chama a função de busca procurando por todos os valores possíveis desde um menor até um maior que todos os elementos do vetor
- como só tem valores pares não vai achar nenhum dos ímpares e como procura por todos valores possíveis deve achar todos os pares, e assim testa tudo sem stress
- como é chato ficar procurando o programa retorna o índice do valor encontrado no vetor e o valor na posição, e assim responde a pergunta óbvia: *"o valor é esse mesmo?"*

#### saída do teste para um vetor de 10 elementos

```
    10 valores, v[0] = 0, v[9] = 18

==> nao encontrou -2 no vetor
==> nao encontrou -1 no vetor
==> busca por 0 retornou 0, v[0] = 0
==> nao encontrou 1 no vetor
==> busca por 2 retornou 1, v[1] = 2
==> nao encontrou 3 no vetor
==> busca por 4 retornou 2, v[2] = 4
==> nao encontrou 5 no vetor
==> busca por 6 retornou 3, v[3] = 6
==> nao encontrou 7 no vetor
==> busca por 8 retornou 4, v[4] = 8
==> nao encontrou 9 no vetor
==> busca por 10 retornou 5, v[5] = 10
==> nao encontrou 11 no vetor
==> busca por 12 retornou 6, v[6] = 12
==> nao encontrou 13 no vetor
==> busca por 14 retornou 7, v[7] = 14
==> nao encontrou 15 no vetor
==> busca por 16 retornou 8, v[8] = 16
==> nao encontrou 17 no vetor
==> busca por 18 retornou 9, v[9] = 18
==> nao encontrou 19 no vetor
==> nao encontrou 20 no vetor
```

#### O programa de teste

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t tamanho = 10;
    LLI* vetor = (ULL*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(ULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tamanho; i += 1)
        *(i + vetor) = (int)(i + i);
    // o vetor tem apenas valores pares
    // para ficar facil de testar:
    // esta ordenado de 0 ao final e nao 
    // tem nenhum valor impar
    printf("\n    %llu valores, v[%llu] = %lli, v[%llu] = %lli\n\n",
        tamanho,
        (size_t)0, *vetor,
        tamanho - 1,
        *(vetor + tamanho - 1));
    for (LLI alvo = -2; alvo <= (LLI)(tamanho + tamanho);
         alvo += 1)
    {
        LLI res = busca_N_aria(alvo, vetor, 0, tamanho - 1);
        if (res >= 0)
            printf(
                "==> busca por %lli retornou"
                " %lli, v[%llu] = %lli\n",
                alvo, res, res, vetor[res]);
        else
            printf(
                "==> nao encontrou %lli no vetor\n", alvo);
    };
    free(vetor);
    vetor = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

#### o codigo completo

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef long long int LLI;
typedef unsigned long long int ULL;
ULL busca_N_aria(LLI, LLI*, size_t, size_t);

int main(void)
{
    size_t tamanho = 10;
    LLI* vetor = (ULL*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(ULL));
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tamanho; i += 1)
        *(i + vetor) = (int)(i + i);
    // o vetor tem apenas valores pares
    // para ficar facil de testar:
    // esta ordenado de 0 ao final e nao 
    // tem nenhum valor impar
//clang-format-off
    printf("\n    %llu valores, v[%llu] = %lli, v[%llu] = %lli\n\n",
        tamanho,
        (size_t)0, *vetor,
        tamanho - 1,
        *(vetor + tamanho - 1));
//clang-format-on
    for (LLI alvo = -2; alvo <= (LLI)(tamanho + tamanho);
         alvo += 1)
    {
        LLI res = busca_N_aria(alvo, vetor, 0, tamanho - 1);
        if (res >= 0)
            printf(
                "==> busca por %lli retornou"
                " %lli, v[%llu] = %lli\n",
                alvo, res, res, vetor[res]);
        else
            printf(
                "==> nao encontrou %lli no vetor\n", alvo);
    };
    free(vetor);
    vetor = NULL;
    return 0;
}

// busca 'alvo' no vetor 'vec' entre os indices
// 'inicio' e 'final'. O vetor e suposto ordenado.
ULL busca_N_aria(LLI alvo, LLI* vec, size_t inicio, size_t final)
{
    const int n_seg = 3;  // 3 para busca ternaria
    if (vec[inicio] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[inicio] == alvo) return inicio;
    if (vec[final] < alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[final] == alvo) return final;
    // define o tamanho de cada segmento
    size_t seg = (final - inicio - 2) / n_seg; 
    if (seg <= 0) seg = 1;
    size_t ini = inicio + 1;
    size_t fim = ini + seg;
    while (1)
    {
        if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
        if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
        if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;  // era o ultimo
        // esta no meio desse segmento entao
        if (vec[fim] > alvo) return busca_N_aria(alvo, vec, ini+1, fim-1);
        ini += seg; // reajusta
        fim += seg;
        if ((final - fim) < seg) fim = final;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

#### um teste da função original com a correção

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int buscaTernaria(int,int*,int);

int main(void)
{
    int tamanho = 11;
    int* vetor   = (int*)malloc(tamanho * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < tamanho; i += 1)
        *(i + vetor) = (int)(i + i);
    printf(
        "\n    %d valores, v[%d] = %d, v[%d] = "
        "%d\n\n",
        tamanho, 0, *vetor, tamanho - 1,
        *(vetor + tamanho - 1));
    for (int alvo = -2; alvo <= (int)(tamanho + tamanho);
         alvo += 1)
    {
        int res = buscaTernaria(alvo, vetor, tamanho);
        if (res >= 0)
            printf("==> busca por %d retornou"
                " %d, v[%d] = %d\n",
                alvo, res, res, vetor[res]);
        else
            printf(
                "==> nao encontrou %d no vetor\n", alvo);
    };
    free(vetor);
    vetor = NULL;
    return 0;
}

int buscaTernaria(int alvo, int* vec, int num)
{
    int ini = 0; // busca entre
    int final = num - 1; // os limites
    int fim = final;  
    if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
    if (vec[fim] < alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
    if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;
    while (1)
    {
        int terco = (fim-ini) / 3;
        if (terco <= 0) terco = 1;
        fim = ini + terco;
        if (vec[ini] > alvo) return -1;  // nao tem mesmo
        if (vec[ini] == alvo) return ini;
        if (vec[fim] == alvo) return fim;  // era o ultimo
        if (vec[fim] > alvo)
        {  // busca nesse segmento
            ini += 1;
            fim -= 1;
        }
        else
        {   // segue adiante: proximo terco
            ini += terco;  // reajusta
            fim += terco; // limites
            if ((final - fim) < terco) fim = final;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```